# C# Chart change colour when a series point goes over a certain value

Tags: c#, colors, charts, linechart, series

I am currently using VS C# and have a chart on my form.

The chart works fine but I am wanting to change the colour (color) of the graph if any of the values in the series hit 255 (the top of the graph)

At the moment I tried this:

```
 GRAPH_READY = false;
 c.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 255;
 c.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 256;
 c.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
 c.Series[s].Points.DataBindY(vals.ToArray());
 c.Series[s].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
 c.Series[s].BorderWidth = 3;
 c.Series[s].BorderColor = Color.Red;

 for (int i = 0; i < c.Series[s].Points.Count; i++)
 {
      //here I'm wanting to check if any of the Y values of the points are over 255 
      if (c.Series[s].YValuesPerPoint == 255) c.Series[s].Color = Color.Red;
      else if (c.Series[s].YValuesPerPoint < 254) c.Series[s].Color = Color.Blue;
 }
 GRAPH_READY = true;
```

I tried the above and it doesnt seem to work  :( the graph goes blue as it starts off below the 255 value, but When i make it go to 255, it stays blue.

[image: This is the graph when points are UNDER 255 (Blue graph which is good)]

[image: This is the graph when points are AT 255 (Blue graph when it should be Red)]

Thanks in advance,

J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm not sure of what values you are binding, it would be better to capture all values above and inclusive of your maximum.

I suggest changing your first IF statement to:

```
if (c.Series[s].YValuesPerPoint >= 255) c.Series[s].Color = Color.Red;
```

Comment: Aaaah good shout @setherith, I also noticed i'm not using my count at any point... Where's the restart day button.